# Can I use the F-Keys on Windows Touch Keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, on-screen-keyboard

Is it possible to access the F-Keys using Windows Touch Keyboard,

I'm using Windows 10.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it possible to access the F-Keys using Windows Touch Keyboard?

Yes. Full instructions below:

> The Windows 10 keyboard was originally designed for touch users on tablets, so by default the keyboard is kept to a limited set of keys than you'd find in a regular PC. This allows Microsoft to make the keyboard bigger and easier to tap the keys, but at the cost of some missing functionality -- like the Function (Fn) Keys and number keys row, and the ALT key.
>
> To switch to full keyboard layout, you have to turn the options on in
>   Windows Settings.
>
> 1. Open Windows 10 Settings from the Start menu.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Click or Tap on "Devices".
>
>    [image]
> 3. Click or Tap on "Typing".
>
>    [image]
> 4. Toggle "on" the setting for Add the standard keyboard layout as a touch keyboard option.
>
>    [image: windows10 devices typing standard]
> 5. Click or Tap the keyboard icon in the task bar.
>
>    [image]
>
>    (If you don't see the icon, right-click or long-press on the taskbar
>      and select "Show touch keyboard button.")
> 6. Click or tap the keyboard button at the bottom right of the on-screen keyboard.
>
>    [image]
> 7. Select the standard keyboard icon. It's the right-most icon.
>
>    [image]
>
> Now you'll have access to the ALT, Function, Tab and other keys
>   missing from the default touch keyboard. To switch back, head to that
>   keyboard button again to change the layout.

Source [Getting the full layout in Windows 10's Touch Keyboard :](http://quicklaunch.ucworkspace.com/support/solutions/articles/3000054002-getting-the-full-layout-in-windows-10-s-touch-keyboard)